# Simulate click inside iframe with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, onclick, simulation

I have HTML containing an iframe and 2 buttons, master and slave. The slave simply displays "clicked" upon being clicked on while the master simulates the clicking action. It works fine, but I'd also like the same behavior to be applied to a slave inside an iframe. Is it possible to achieve such a functionality? The current code ignores the iframe.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('#master').click(function() {
            simulateClick(50, 50); //iframe position
            simulateClick(50, 100); //slave position
        });
        $('#slave').click(function() {
            alert('clicked');
        });
    });

    function simulateClick(x, y) {
        jQuery(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).click();
    }
```

Comment: use iframe document for `elementFromPoint`. Assumes iframe is on same domain or you can't access it

Answer (score 0):

The document ready function does not guarantee the iframe has loaded. I would guess it is running *before* the iframe has loaded. Try something like:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#IframeID').load(function () {
       $('#master').click(function() {
            simulateClick(50, 50); //iframe position
            simulateClick(50, 100); //slave position
        });
        $('#slave').click(function() {
            alert('clicked');
        });
    });
});
```